# Error al encriptar contraseña en Symfony 5 con encodePassword

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

Cuando envío el formulario obtengo el siguiente error: [image: Me pide que el la función debe recibir un UserInterface, sin embargo, mis compañeros no lo han necesitado]

> ¿Por qué no podría pasar por parámetro directamente el objeto User?
> ¿Dónde tendría que añadir esta interfaz para que me reconozca el objeto User creado?
> Estoy aprendiendo a utilizar y he desarrollado mucho con Angular que tiene cierto parecido.
> En el tutorial que he estado siguiendo realiza también un ejemplo parecido a este sin la necesidad de
> crear una interfaz de usuario. He intentado seguir también la documentación de Symfony pero veo
> también que hace prácticamente lo mismo que estoy intentando yo. Si alguien pudiera echarme una mano
> con esto se lo agradecería.

El código del controlador es el siguiente:`<?php

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Form\UserType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

class RegistroController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/registro', name: 'registro')]
    
    public function index(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class,$user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $user->setBaeando(false);
            $user->setPassword($passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user,$form['password']->getData()));
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
            $this->addFlash('exito','se ha registrado exitosamente');
            return $this->redirectToRoute('registro');
        }
        return $this->render('registro/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'RegistroController',
            'formulario'=>$form->createView()
        ]);
    }
}`
```

Comment: La entidad `App\Entity\User` debe implementar `UserInterface` cosa que no está haciendo

Comment: Esta interfaz para ser exactos: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.4/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserInterface.php